# webGL story sphere popups

Tags: javascript, popup, webgl

I am trying to adapt the really cool looking WebGL Story Sphere, source code and css [here](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Globe).  There's one big problem: once you click on a news article, the text of the article in the popup is always the same.  I want to modify the code so that when you click on an article, the right text appears in the popup.

I'm working from a set of article texts that I specify in the code, e.g. `var captions = ["good","better","best"]`.  Though the article titles and images populate correctly in the popup, I can't get the text to do so.  Can you help me??  Here's what I've got:

```
// function code
var passvar = null; // failed attempt to store texts for later
function initialize() {
  math = tdl.math;
  fast = tdl.fast;
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  g_fpsTimer = new tdl.fps.FPSTimer();
  hack();

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp, false);

  // Create a canvas 2d for making textures with text.
  g_canvas2d = document.createElement('canvas');

  window.two2w = window.two2h = g_tilesize; 

  g_canvas2d.width = two2w;
  g_canvas2d.height = two2h;
  g_ctx2d = g_canvas2d.getContext("2d");

  window.gl = wu.create3DContext(canvas);
  if (g_debug) {
    gl = wd.makeDebugContext(gl, undefined, LogGLCall);
  }
  //gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, gl.TRUE);

  // Here is where I specify article titles, images, captions
  // Titles and images populate the popup correctly, captions don't...

  var titles = ["a","b","c"];
  var captions = ["good","better","best"];
  var images = ['imagesphere/assets/1.jpg', 
                'imagesphere/assets/bp/2.png', 
                'imagesphere/assets/bp/3.png'
                ];

  var headlines = titles.concat( titles);
  var blurbs = captions.concat( captions);

  var tmpImages = [];
  var tmpHeadlines = [];
  var tmpCaptions = [];

  // make a bunch of textures.
  for (var ii = 0; ii < g_imagesDownGrid; ++ii) {
    var textures = [];
    for (var jj = 0; jj < g_imagesAcrossGrid; ++jj) {
      var imgTexture = new ImgTexture();

      textures.push(imgTexture);
      if (tmpImages.length == 0) {
        tmpImages = images.slice();
      }
      if (tmpHeadlines.length == 0) {
        tmpHeadlines = headlines.slice();
      }
      if (tmpCaptions.length == 0) {
          tmpCaptions = blurbs.slice();
      }
      var rando = math.randomInt(tmpImages.length);
      var img = tmpImages.splice(rando, 1)[0];
      var headline = tmpHeadlines.splice(rando, 1)[0];
      var caption = tmpCaptions.splice(rando, 1)[0];
      passvar = caption;

      if (img.indexOf('videoplay.jpg') > -1){
        window.vidtexture = imgTexture;
        images = images.slice(1); // dont use that thumb again.
        headlines = 'WebGL Brings Video To the Party as Well'
      }

      imgTexture.load(img, /* "[" + jj + "/" + ii + "]" + */ headline);
    }
    g_textures.push(textures);
  }

  // And here's where I try to put this in a popup, finally
  // But passvar, the stored article text, never refreshes!!!

 <div id="story" class="prettybox" style="display:none"> 
    <img class="close" src="imagesphere/assets/close.png">
    <div id="storyinner">
        <input id = "mytext">
            <script>document.getElementById("mytext").value = passvar;</script>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And here is my click handler code:

```
   function sphereClick(e){
   window.console && console.log('click!', e, e.timeStamp);

   var selected = g_textures[sel.y][sel.x];
   window.selected = selected;

   animateGL('eyeRadius', glProp('eyeRadius'), 4, 500); 

   var wwidth   = $(window).width(),
       wheight  = $(window).height(),
       story    = $('#story').width( ~~(wwidth / 7 * 4) ).height( ~~(wheight / 6 * 5) ), 
       width    = story.width(),
       height   = story.height(),
       miniwidth = 30;

   story.detach()
    .find('#storyinner').find('h3,img,caption').remove().end().end()
    .show();

   story.css({
     left        :   e.pageX,
     top         :   e.pageY,
     marginLeft  :   - width / 2,
     marginTop   :   - height / 2

   }).appendTo($body); // we remove and put back on the DOM to reset it to the correct position.

   $('style.anim.story').remove();
   $('<style class="anim story">')
      .text( '.storyopen #story { left : ' + (wwidth  / 3 * 2) + 'px !important;  top : ' + wheight / 2 + 'px !important; }' )
      .appendTo($body);
   $(selected.img).prependTo('#storyinner').parent();

   $('<h3>').text(selected.msg.replace(/\(.*/,'')).prependTo('#storyinner');

   $body.addClass('storyopen');


} // eo sphereClick()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here, but here's a start. It won't solve your problem, but it will help you avoid issues like this.

---

`var passvar = null;` is a global variable.

Your loop `for (var ii = 0; ...` sets that global variable to a new value on every iteration.

Later, you click something and the global variable `passvar` is never changed.

If you want to use this pattern, you need to set `passvar` from your click handler so it has the value that was clicked. Since you didn't actually post your click handlers, it's hard to advise more.

---

But this is also a bad pattern, functions take arguments for a good reason. Since you have to find your clicked item in the click handler anyway, why not pass it directly which does involve a shared global variable at all?

```
var handleMouseUp = function(event) {
  var story = findClickedThing(event);
  if (obj) {
    showPopup(story.texture, story.caption);
  }
}
```

---

Which brings me to this:

```
var titles = ["a","b","c"];
var captions = ["good","better","best"];
var images = ['imagesphere/assets/1.jpg', 
              'imagesphere/assets/bp/2.png', 
              'imagesphere/assets/bp/3.png'
              ];
```

When you have 3 arrays, all of the same length, each array describing a different property of an object, you are *doing it wrong*. What you want, is *one* array of objects instead.

```
var stories = [
  {
    title: "a",
    caption: "good",
    image: "imagesphere/assets/1.jpg"
  }, {
    title: "b",
    caption: "better",
    image: "imagesphere/assets/bp/2.jpg"
  }, {
    title: "c",
    caption: "best",
    image: "imagesphere/assets/bp/3.jpg"
  },
];

console.log(stories[1].caption); // "better"
```

Now once you find the clicked object, you can just ask it what it's caption is. And you can pass the whole object to the popup maker. And no field is handled differently or passed around in a different manner, because you are not passing around the fields. You are *passsing the entire object*.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very helpful.  I am new to javascript.  I will keep working on the clean way to do this, but in the meantime my click handler has been posted.